# Can I change nivo slider's nivo-control anchor links to use custom text?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

```
<div class="nivo-controlNav">
  <a class="nivo-control" rel="0">1</a>
  <a class="nivo-control" rel="1">2</a>
  <a class="nivo-control" rel="2">3</a>
  <a class="nivo-control" rel="3">4</a>
</div>
```

This is what nivo spits out. i want to change the anchors to a custom text for each slide. I don't want to hack it, and I couldn't find any nivo documentation to see if there was a support for it. Does anyone know if this is possible?

TL;DR - Basically, I want to use custom anchor text instead of dots. I want the anchor texts for SEO purposes.

Comment: The buttons are generated dynamically depending on the number of slides. You could - (instead of taking the slide index) find in the NIVO code where it appends the `<a class="nivo-control"></a>` elements and insert into it for example an image `alt` attribute text. And that's not hacking :)

Comment: That's a good idea too. I was actually planning to use it's afterLoad function and then just change it with jQuery, so then maintenance would be more tolerable this way.